# I am having problems with CSS when I open my code in localhost

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, discord, localhost

I saw this code in an article about discord Oauth2. As I have two HTML files so how do I connect both of them in this line: `res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });`

And my both HTML files are not in a specific folder it's in the main file.

When I open my code with VS code live server it looks like this:

[image]

But when I open it with localhost:53134 it looks like this:

[image]

This is my index.html code:

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Montserrat Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Changes this to your bot's name -->
  <title>Discord Bot Website Template</title>

  <!-- Change the content attribute's value to your bot's description -->
  <meta name="description" content="An opensource discord bot website template that you can use to make your bot seem more professional!">

  <!-- Change the content attribute's value to your name -->
  <meta name="author" content="TrustedMercury">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/theTrendingStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/all.css" />

</head>

<body class="bg-shinyGray overflow-x-hidden">
  <nav id="navigationBar" class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between p-6 bg-sweetBlack">
    <div class="left flex flex-row items-center ml-10 md:ml-20 text-white">
      <img src="images/botLogo.png" width="48px" height="48px" class="mr-2 hidden md:inline pointer-events-none noselect" />
      <a href="index.html" class="mx-4 text-xl hover:text-blurple">Home</a>
      <a href="pricing.html" class="mx-4 text-xl hover:text-blurple hidden md:inline">Pricing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right mr-10 md:mr-20">
      <a href="YOUR-BOT-INVITE-HERE" target="_blank" class="px-8 py-3 whitespace-no-wrap bg-blurple text-white rounded-lg text-xl font-semibold hover:bg-beautyPurple"><i class="fab fa-discord mr-1"></i> Invite</a>
    
        <div id="info">
        Hoi!
        </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="container" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-40 text-center">
      <span class="text-2xl md:text-5xl font-semibold text-white">Changing the way servers work</span>
      <span class="text-gray-400 text-lg md:text-xl max-w-xl font-light">Helping servers grow exponentially with a simple solution. Make your server active and entertain your community with a simple solution - <b>a single discord bot</b>!</span>
      <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row mt-8">
        <a href="YOUR-BOT-INVITE-HERE" target="_blank" class="text-2xl hvr-grow bg-blurple p-4 md:px-8 mx-4 my-4 rounded-lg">Invite the bot now!</a>
        <a href="YOUR-SUPPORT-SERVER-INVITE-HERE" target="_blank" class="text-2xl hvr-grow text-white bg-sweetBlack p-4 md:px-8 mx-4 my-4 rounded-lg border-blurple border-2">Join the Support Server</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <svg class="bg-blurple" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#1D1E23" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,160L48,138.7C96,117,192,75,288,74.7C384,75,480,117,576,160C672,203,768,245,864,261.3C960,277,1056,267,1152,240C1248,213,1344,171,1392,149.3L1440,128L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
    <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center w-full bg-blurple">
      <img src="images/discordUI.png" class="max-w-xs md:max-w-5xl noselect pointer-events-none" />
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center noselect">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center text-4xl mb-4">
          <span class="font-montserrat font-black">200+</span>
          <span class="font-montserrat font-black">SERVERS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center text-4xl my-4">
          <span class="font-montserrat font-black">14500+</span>
          <span class="font-montserrat font-black">USERS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center text-4xl mt-4">
          <span class="font-montserrat font-black">2300+</span>
          <span class="font-montserrat font-black">CHANNELS</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#7289DA" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L48,240C96,256,192,288,288,304C384,320,480,320,576,288C672,256,768,192,864,138.7C960,85,1056,43,1152,48C1248,53,1344,107,1392,133.3L1440,160L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center mb-10">
      <span class="text-lg text-gray-400 font-semibold">Copyright © Kevin Thomas 2020</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <a id="login" style="display: none;" href="Oauth link here">Identify Yourself</a>

  <script>
         function generateRandomString() {
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            let randStr = '';
 
            for (let i = 0; i < 20 + rand; i++) {
                randStr += String.fromCharCode(33 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 94));
            }
 
            return randStr;
        }
 
        window.onload = function () {
            const fragment = parseQuery(window.location.href);
            if (fragment.access_token) {
                const urlState = fragment.state;
                const stateParameter = localStorage.getItem('stateParameter');
                if (stateParameter !== atob(decodeURIComponent(urlState))) {
                    return console.log('You may have been clickjacked!');
                }
 
                const accessToken = fragment.access_token;
                const tokenType = fragment.token_type;
 
                fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
                    headers: {
                        authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`
                    }
                })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then( (response) => {
                        console.log(response);

 
                        const { username, discriminator, avatar } = response;

                        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = ` ${username}#${discriminator}`;

                        let user = provider.getResourceOwner(`${accessToken}`);

                            let avatar1 = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/'  +  user.id + '/'  + user.avatar + '.png ?size=225';

                        document.getElementsByClassName("avatar-img").src = avatar1;

                    })
                    .catch(console.error);
            } else {
                const randStr = generateRandomString();
                localStorage.setItem('stateParameter', randStr);
 
                document.getElementById('login').href += `&state=${encodeURIComponent(btoa(randStr))}`;
                document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        function parseQuery(queryString) {
            var query = {};
            var pairs = (queryString[0] === '?' ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
                query[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
            }
            return query;
        }
    </script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my javascript code:

```js
    const app = require('express')();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let access_token;
    let token_type;
    if (req.query.code) {
        const accessCode = req.query.code;
        const data = {
            client_id     : 'client id here',
            client_secret : 'client secret here',
            grant_type    : 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri  : 'http://localhost:3000',
            code          : accessCode,
            scope         : 'identify'
        };

        const res = await fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token', {
            method  : 'POST',
            body    : new URLSearchParams(data),
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });

        const info = await res.json();

        token_type = info.token_type;
        access_token = info.access_token;

        const post = await fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
            headers : {
                authorization : `${token_type} ${access_token}`
            }
        });

        const user = await post.json();
    }

    if (token_type && access_token && req.query.state) {
        res
            .status(200)
            .redirect(
                `http://localhost:3000/?code=${req.query.code}&state=${req.query
                    .state}&access_token=${access_token}&token_type=${token_type}`
            );
    } else {
        res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
    }

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Why are you using multiple tag closing formats for your stylesheets references?` <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/theTrendingStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/all.css" />`

Comment: What is the difference between these two folders? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/theTrendingStyle.css">` and ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/all.css" />`?

Comment: There are many different CSS folders with different elements some have all the colors and fonts and some have the margins and all

Comment: I noticed that the first stylesheet reference has a delimiter `/` and the other one doesn't

Comment: Is it a reference to the same `styles` folder?

Comment: Remove the delimiter `/` if the files are in the same folder so it becomes `href=styles/...`

Comment: Yes I removed the delimiter / still, it is not showing the css

Comment: Where is the `trendingStyles.css`? Inside `styles` folder or in a child folder of `styles`?

Comment: It's inside the styles folder not in a child folder.

Comment: Something definitely works on the liver server that is not working on the localhost

Comment: Yes, something is wrong.

Comment: Try adding the dependencies that rely on an internet connection, those beginning with `https://` after the local ones

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what to add and where. Please clarify it.